# Excel - Match Cells and Create List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which contains a list of colleagues by their branch number, and I need to be able to select a branch on Sheet 1 say, which will then display a list of colleagues from only that branch, but I can't work out how to achieve this.  Can anyone offer any help?  I can use VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH to gain the 1st colleague name, but how do I then find the rest of the colleagues associated with the same branch number?

SHEET 1

```
1234    Bill
1234    Jane
1234    Sam
1234    Chloe
1234    Charlie
4321    Abbey
4321    Susan
4321    John
4321    Ste
2541    Claire
2541    Mike
2541    Harry
2541    Craig
```

And then on SHEET 2, There is a drop down box, containing the branch numbers (1234, 4321 and 2541) and I want the individual colleague names to appear in cells underneath based on the branch that's selected.

Hope that makes sense, and I hope someone can help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Jonathan

***** EDIT *****

Sorry for the delay in getting these posted, I've been crazy busy!  Really appreciate any help anyone can give on this though!

[SHEET 1 WHICH CONTAINS THE NAME DATA FOR EACH BRANCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwuUQ.png)

[SHEET 2 WHICH CONTAINS THE LOOKUP SHEET, WHERE I WANT IT TO FIND THE COLLEAGUE NAMES AND POPULATE THE LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayQ8p.png)

Answer (score 1):

if your list is unsorted then use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!B:B)))/(Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!B:B))=$A$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

---

If your list is sorted on branch then use this formula:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)>COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,$A$1),"",INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+ROW(1:1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,  That doesn't seem to be working for me... admittedly, this is all a little out of my excel league, so i'm struggling to understand what the formula you've listed is doing, but I can't seem to make it work at my end.  I've uploaded an example of what i'm trying to do here... https://1drv.ms/f/s!Avg7dGQP7bD8hqAietL-t5CM1AMn7w if you would be kind enough to have a look and it may explain what i'm trying to do a bit better??

Comment: Sorry I don't down load files from public forums. Put pictures of bother pages in you original post.

Comment: I've edited my original post with the images of sheet 1 and sheet 2, if anyone is able to help me get this working?? Thanks for the help so far @scott-craner